# Load UITableView sections by NSDate from NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, performance, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an NSArray of NSDictionaries in my app. In each dictionary I hold an NSDate called "RunDate." The problem I am having now is that the code I am trying to do it with is very inefficient. Basically I only want one section per date out of all the dictionaries. Then in each section (sorted by that date), I would load the appropriate dictionary that had that date.

In the code below I made a new NSArray of NSDictionarys which held a date and number of that date (so I could know how many rows are in each section). The problem is, this code looks and feels very inefficient and I was wondering if there were any ways my code is incorrect or could be improved upon. There can be over 500 entries and the code I have now would be very slow. Does anyone have any suggestions on it?

```
    runArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    runArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"RunArray"] mutableCopy];

    runDictTableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in runArray) {
        NSDictionary *runInfoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSDate *theDate = [dict objectForKey:@"RunDate"];

        //Check if we already have this date in the saved run array
        BOOL goToNextDict = FALSE;
        for (NSDictionary *savedDict in runDictTableArray) {
            if ([theDate compare:[savedDict objectForKey:@"RunDate"]] == NSOrderedSame) {
                goToNextDict = TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (goToNextDict)
            continue;
        ////////////////////////////

        //Now we check how many more we have of this date
        int numbOfDate = 1;
        int index = (int)[runArray indexOfObject:dict];
        for (int i = index; i < [runArray count]; i++) {
            NSDictionary *dictInner = [runArray objectAtIndex:i];
            if ([theDate compare:[dictInner objectForKey:@"RunDate"]] == NSOrderedSame) {
                numbOfDate++;
            }
        }
        ////////////////////////////

        [runInfoDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numbOfDate] forKey:@"DateAmount"];
        [runInfoDict setValue:theDate forKey:@"Date"];
        [runDictTableArray addObject:runInfoDict];
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using NSSortDescriptor? It would probably be easier that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. You probably only need 1 `NSMutableDictionary`, rather than a `NSMutableArray` of `NSDictionary`.  While looping through `runArray`, check if your dictionary has a value for your date (`objectForKey` returns a value).  If it does, add 1 to the count. If it does not, add that date as a key to the dictionary with a value of 1.  This way, you won't have to do the inner loop to get the number of times a date occurs.  You won't need the 'go to next dictionary' logic either, I would think.
2. `runArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` doesn't really do anything since you're immediately re-assigning `runArray`.
3. Consider using `NSInteger` over regular `int`, `NSInteger` will give you the appropriate size for whatever architecture your app is running on.
4. There's some cool syntax shortcuts you might like.  You can avoid `[runInfoDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numbOfDate]...` by simply writing `[runInfoDict setValue:@(numbOfDate) ...`, which will put the value into `NSNumber` for you.